# Object deleted/unreferenced check

Tags: c#

How do I know an object has no reference to it and at that point it should be deleted by the .NET garbage collector?

I'm doing a number of cloning of an object. The reason why I'm cloning it because it is a same object but it has different values later on. When I unreference the object from a property of some class, I don't know where that certain cloned object is being referenced anywhere in the program. My idea is to definitely know that a certain unreferenced object should not be referenced anywhere. If they are referenced somewhere else, I need to unreference it (fix it).

My idea is to unreference a certain clone of an object everywhere in the system to garbage collect and free up space.

Is there anyway I check this object .NET? Is there any libraries or something like that. I'm feeling the object I think I deleted is still being referenced somewhere in my program while running, because this program is huge. Because it is referenced somewhere else, it is not being garbage collected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might want to use a memory profiler to track down the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) class to hold a reference to your object, and check its `IsAlive` property to know whether the object still exists or has been gargabe collected (finalized and deallocated). The principal advantage of `WeakReference` for your case is this reference doesn't prevent the GC to dispose the object target.

You can explicitly invoke the garbage collector before the check to lower the probablity there's no other reference to that object and the GC just didn't notice yet. However, you can't reliably tell whether there is / is not a certain amount of reference to your object 'in the wild'.

Comment: what do you mean by your last sentence "reference to your object 'in the wild'"

Comment: 'in the wild' = anywhere else in the application domain, including places you aren't aware even might exist :-)